# Can't connect to Windows Phone Store from devices

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store

We are implementing in app purchase plugin from Prime31 for Windows Phone Store on our application. On the emulator all purchases is success and the responses are valid.

However, we currently unavailable to do any purchase from our devices. Our client also get the same response from their devices. Store response is "Service not available, The store isn't available at the moment. Please check back in a bit." with error code 805a01f4 each time we do purchase from the developed app. You can see captured message here http://s12.postimg.org/syhctvpil/10841578_10152855930562158_641306387_n.jpg

Bad thing is, we can do purchase for other downloaded apps from all devices. So we can be sure if this is not a problem of connection, region or timezone of the device. We have changed region and timezone, reset the device, put back to previous settings, and reset the device again. But nothing helps.

Is there anyone ever face the same problem? Any advice would be very helpful.

Note: The app is currently hidden from store listing. But we assured that this is not a problem, because purchase is valid on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last we found the answer. A fellow describe it at here [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d50bc575-4167-4602-b64e-297143092814/how-to-resolve-error-code-805a01f4?forum=aiaforwinphone)

To be short, this is signing problem. WP store seems to be accepts purchase only from app that signed from the store. So any purchase with app signed with VS will bring this error.

I hope this will be useful for someone who faced the same problem, as we can't find it documented anywhere else.